# JAAD cannot read m4a

Tags: scala, javasound, m4a

What I wish to do is to generate a preview for every m4a file. I am trying to do this with Java Sound and JAAD.

Here is my attempt in Scala

```
import java.io.{File, FileOutputStream}
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem

/**
 * Created by khanguyen on 7/21/15.
 */
object Main extends App {
  val filePath = "audio.m4a"

  val file = new File(filePath)

  val audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)

  println(audio.getFrameLength) // return -1

  println(audio.getFormat) // return PCM_SIGNED 0.0 Hz, 0 bit, 0 channels, 0 bytes/frame, 

  val output = new FileOutputStream("outputaudio.m4a")

  var buffer = Array.fill[Byte](1024)(0)

  for (i <- 0 to 1024) {
    audio.read(buffer, i * 1024, 1024)
    buffer.take(10).map(println)
    output.write(buffer)
  }

  audio.close()
  output.flush()
  output.close()
}
```

I cannot read anything from the audio input stream. The frameLength is said to be `-1`. After a read pass, all the bytes in Array[Byte] are still `0`. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting a `-1` in `audio.getFrameLength` it is because the file format is not supported.

```
val audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)
                                                  //> javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input
                                                  //|  stream from input file
                                                  //|   at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:
                                                  //| 1187)
                                                  //|   at forcomp.wc$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(forcomp.wc.scala:15)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$$anonfun$$exe
                                                  //| cute$1.apply$mcV$sp(WorksheetSupport.scala:76)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.redirected(W
                                                  //| orksheetSupport.scala:65)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$.$execute(Wor
                                                  //| ksheetSupport.scala:75)
                                                  //|   at forcomp.wc$.main(forcomp.wc.scala:5)
                                                  //|   at forcomp.wc.main(forcomp.wc.scala)

      println(audio.getFrameLength) // return -1
```

Anyways, I've tested it with a pet m4a example file but in the javax.sound.AudioSystem api (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) you will find more information about the supported file types, AAC (m4a extentions are part of AAC coding) should be supported.

Comment: The format indeed is not supported. What was the result of your test?

Comment: I already posted the result above: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input. If I where you I would convert my file to a different encoding an try with that..

Comment: *MFSampledSP* on Windows or *CASampledSP* on OS X may help you reading AAC/m4a. See [SampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/sampledsp.html).